# What equipment and setup do I need to be able to hear both my vocals and guitar through headphones while playing?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, voice, amplifiers, equipment

I'm moving into an apartment after playing acoustic guitar in a house for the past year and starting to learn to sing; I now have to be a little more quiet.

I want to play an electric guitar and hear the sound through headphones.

I want to be able to sing and hear myself through the same headphones.

Is this possible? I know very little about electrical music equipment. If so, what would I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of equipment do you have? How much money are you willing to spend?

Here's what I'd suggest. You need

- a small mixer (like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005EHILV4))
- if you have a guitar amp with a headphone output, you're all set; otherwise you may need an amp simulator (like [this one](https://www.thomann.de/gb/line6_pocket_pod.htm) or [this one](https://www.thomann.de/gb/boss_gt_001.htm))
- a microphone and stand
- a headphone
- a bunch of cables

Then you have two ways of connecting things:

if your guitar amp/ amp sim has an aux input and a headphone output, you can use the mixer as a preamp for the microphone, connect the mixer output to the aux input of the amp, and plug the headphone into the headphone output of the amp.

Otherwise (and this what I'd recommend), plug the output of the guitar amp/ amp sim and the microphone into the mixer, and the use the headphone output of the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

You could get yourself an audio mixer, which would probably do the job. Make sure you get one with different volume knobs for each input source though, otherwise one source may drown out the other.

You can buy a relatively small, cheap one online; they're pretty common. I bought myself one Amazon not too long ago (I think it was just the first one I saw when searching "audio mixer"), and while the audio fidelity isn't great as I only paid £20 for it, it's perfectly effective for what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The mixer idea will work well, but then you'll need a mic. and stand to sing through as well.

I advocate using a mixer for the guitar, with headphones plugged in, but put over just one ear. Perhaps no need for a mic., as you'll listen to guitar in one ear, and your own voice through the open ear.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go on amazon and pick yourself up a cheap android/iOS condenser microphone. It plugs into your phone and then it has a headphone jack on the back of the microphone so you can use headphones to hear yourself and your guitar at the same time while you play